# Autocomplete for IBM Cloud CLI on Mac High Sierra and Zsh?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I am having trouble with `zsh` autocompletion for IBM Cloud CLI tools.

I put the following line into my `.zshrc`, but don't get autocompletion working.

`source /usr/local/ibmcloud/bx/zsh_autocomplete`

Comment: Can you check that the file `zsh_autocomplete` is at that path? Or is it "/usr/local/ibmcloud/zsh_autocomplete"?

Comment: it is at `/usr/local/ibmcloud/bx/zsh_autocomplete`. I have installed `IBM Cloud CLI tools` with `homebrew`

Comment: I am on a Linux system with bash, so cannot test your config, but it is the most common developer config. Any errors or just that the commands do not expand in zsh?

Comment: They just don't expand. I have autocompletion for many other CLI tools working perfectly (aws for example)

Comment: @data_henrik Please check answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developer, this feature is not implemented yet, although documented.
Fix expected in version 0.9.

https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-release/issues/49#issuecomment-415593301